# How should a composable higher order function be referenced with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, higher-order-functions, android-jetpack-compose

*I'm using Jetpack Compose version 0.1.0-dev13*

I've written a simple composable function which uses an [`AdapterList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/foundation/package-summary#adapterlist) with a list of items. (Note: this works as intended when using a lambda instead of a reference using the `::` syntax)

```
AdapterList(data = items, itemCallback = ::ItemCard)
```

For reference, the signature of `AdapterList` is as follows:

```
@Composable
fun <T> AdapterList(
    data: List<T>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    itemCallback: @Composable (T) -> Unit
)
```

In the interest of better facilitating individual previews, I've factored the item callback out into a separate composable function.

The `ItemCard` function looks like this:

```
@Composable
private fun ItemCard(item: Item) {
    Card(
        color = item.type.getColor()
    ) {
        Text(
            item.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
        )
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that the `ItemCard` function has a signature of `@Composable (Item) -> Unit` which should satisfy the type of the `itemCallback` parameter of `AdapterList`.

No error shows in the IDE at this point.

However, when trying to build the project, the following error is displayed:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<Item, Unit> but (Item) -> Unit was expected

What is the difference between the two types and how should `ItemCard` (or the reference to it) be changed to satisfy the type constraints?

Comment: I have seen this too. I have assumed that it is a bug/limitation in the Kotlin compiler plugin for Compose. After I create a reproducible test case, I'll ask in `#compose` in Kotlinlang Slack and will add an answer here if we find a resolution.

Comment: Sounds great, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, [the preliminary analysis](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1592081839193800) is: it's a bug.

(note: the link in preceding paragraph requires Kotlinlang Slack access)

I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158892712) for this (which was subsequently marked as a duplicate of [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149424759)). So, in the meantime, you are stuck with lambda expressions. But, keep tabs on the issue, as it's possible that we will find out about a workaround there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
AdapterList(data = items){ ItemCard(item = it) }
```

or

```
AdapterList(data = items, itemCallback= { ItemCard(it) } )
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my working solution for now. However, shouldn't it be possible to use a callable reference? It's neater to use the reference form IMO and I'm interested to know why it's not possible this way.

Comment: It equals to `AdapterList(data = items, itemCallback= { ItemCard(it) } )` where the `itemCallback` is `(Item) -> Unit`.

Comment: yeah, I appreciate that they're functionally equivalent, even perhaps at compiler level. It's purely a preference of code style; it makes it clearer at first glance that there's no additional work being done in the lambda. I'll accept your answer after some time if no one can tell me why it doesn't work here